# Ellipse to path convertion using javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, ellipse, path.js

```
<ellipse cx="150" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50"   style="fill:yellow;stroke:purple;stroke-width:2" />
```

How can I convert svg ellipse tag to svg path  In javascript

```
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#DE1414" d="M170.821,..........z"></path>
```

Comment: Convert to two arcs ('a' or 'A')?

Comment: Is it possible to convert ellipse to path d attribute?

Comment: ... Arcs are one of the commands available in a path, via an a or A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The d attribute for the path is made of 4 cubic Bézier curves, one for each quadrant. In order to calculate the control point positions I'm using a constant `kappa=0.5522847498;`. I'm taken the value for the kappa from [Drawing a circle with Bézier Curves](http://whizkidtech.redprince.net/bezier/circle/)

The function `getD(cx, cy, rx, ry)` takes as attributes the coords of the center of the ellipse cx and cy and the radiuses of the ellipse rx and ry.

```js
function getD(cx, cy, rx, ry) {
        var kappa=0.5522847498;
        var ox = rx * kappa; // x offset for the control point
        var oy = ry * kappa; // y offset for the control point 
        let d = `M${cx - rx},${cy}`;
            d+= `C${cx - rx}, ${cy - oy}, ${cx - ox}, ${cy - ry}, ${cx}, ${cy - ry},`
            d+= `C${cx + ox}, ${cy - ry}, ${cx + rx}, ${cy - oy}, ${cx + rx}, ${cy},`
            d+= `C${cx + rx}, ${cy + oy}, ${cx + ox}, ${cy + ry}, ${cx}, ${cy + ry},`
            d+= `C${cx - ox}, ${cy + ry}, ${cx - rx}, ${cy + oy}, ${cx - rx}, ${cy},`
            d+= `z`;
       return d;
  }

thePath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", getD(150, 80, 100, 50))
```

```html
<svg>
<ellipse cx="150" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50"   style="fill:yellow;stroke:purple;stroke-width:2" />
<path id="thePath" d="" style="fill:red"/>
</svg>
```

This is an image showing the positions of the control points for the 4 Béziers used to draw the path ellipse:

[image]

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting:

> Actually this code working for conversion of ellipse to path but the height,width,x and y position of path different from previous ellipse.

In order to prove that this is not the case I'm adding a comparation between the bounding box of both the ellipse and the path:

```js
console.log("ellipse",el.getBBox())
console.log("path",pth.getBBox())
```

```html
<svg>
<ellipse id="el" cx="150" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:yellow;stroke:purple;stroke-width:2"></ellipse>
<path id="pth" d="M50,80C50, 52.385762510000006, 94.77152502000001, 30, 150, 30,C205.22847498, 30, 250, 52.385762510000006, 250, 80,C250, 107.61423749, 205.22847498, 130, 150, 130,C94.77152502000001, 130, 50, 107.61423749, 50, 80,z" style="fill:red"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you enxaneta .Path convertion working perfectly but position not of path getting change .

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you. The ellipse and the path are perfectly overlapped. Can you please explain what exactly is not changing?

Comment: Actually this code working for conversion of ellipse to path but the height,width,x and y position of path different from previous ellipse.